# Optimum async flow for cross validation in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to implement cross validation evaluation with Node.js like follows

```
partitions.partitions(dataset, numOfFolds, function(train, test, fold) {
...     
   train_test(classifier, train, test, function(err, results){
   ...
   })
...
})
```

This is the code for partitioning

```
exports.partitions = function(dataset, numOfPartitions, callback) {
    var testSetCount = dataset.length / numOfPartitions;

    for (var iPartition=0; iPartition<numOfPartitions; ++iPartition) {
        var testSetStart = iPartition*testSetCount;
        var partition = exports.partition(dataset, testSetStart, testSetCount);
        callback(partition.train, partition.test, iPartition);
    }
 }
```

`Partitions` simply partitions the dataset and returns the `train` and `test` pairs  for each fold.

The above code works for synchronous `train_test` but now I have asynchronous `train_test`, I wonder how `partitions` should be changed in order to support asynchronous `train_test`. I want to go to the next fold when `train_test` is finished for the current fold.

Comment: Use promises - they will come with integrated error handling.

Comment: Um, you say `Partitions` returns train/test pairs for each fold, but I cannot see it `return`ing anything?