# Synchronous run of included function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a question regarding synchronous run of included function. For example, I have the following code.

```
partitions(dataset, num_of_folds, function(train, test, fold) {
  train_and_test(train,test, function(err, results)
  {
  })
})
```

where `partitions` runs `num_of_folds` times, for deffierent fold it returns different train and test sets. I want to run every iteration of partitions only when `train_and_test` is finished. How to do so?

Comment: Where/how is `partitions` defined? I'm guessing you're getting it from a lib. Which one?

Comment: If you are dealing with an asynchronous call, than you need to alter your code either with the loop or the train_and_test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimum async flow for cross validation in node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424368/optimum-async-flow-for-cross-validation-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your previous question: [Optimum async flow for cross validation in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424368/optimum-async-flow-for-cross-validation-in-node-js), I understand that `partition` is your own function, which splits the dataset into several parts, and then runs the callback (basically `train_and_test` here) for each of those parts.

Your issue now is that `train_and_test` is asynchronous, but you want to wait for each invocation to finish (which is signalled by the its own callback being called, I assume) before running the next one.

One trivial solution is do change your code to keep state, and run the next invocation from the callback. For instance:

```
exports.partitions = function(dataset, numOfPartitions, callback) {
    var testSetCount = dataset.length / numOfPartitions;
    var iPartition=0;
    var iteration = function() {
        if (iPartition<numOfPartitions)
        {
            var testSetStart = iPartition*testSetCount;
            var partition = exports.partition(dataset, testSetStart, testSetCount);
            callback(partition.train, partition.test, iPartition, iteration);
            iPartition++;
        }
    };
    iteration();
};
```

You'll then need to pass the additional callback down to your asynchronous function:

```
partitions(dataset, num_of_folds, function(train, test, fold, callback) {
  train_and_test(train,test, function(err, results)
  {
      callback();
  })
});
```

Note that I haven't tested any of the code above.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to run every iteration of partitions only when train_and_test is finished. How to do so?

That's entirely up to how `partitions` calls the callback you're giving it. If `partitions` calls the callback *normally*, then it will wait for the callback to finish before proceeding. But if it calls is asynchronously, for instance via `nextTick` or `setTimeout` or similar, then the only way you'd be able to tell it to wait would be if it provides a means of telling it that.

If I read your question another way: If `train_and_test` is asynchronous, and `partitions` isn't designed to deal with asynchronous callbacks, you can't make it wait.